# Oculus Quest 2 controller 3D tracking data to blender camera?

Tags: camera, tracking, unreal-engine

I was doing some 3D green screen virtual production and I was not getting very clean 3D tracks so my shots didn't look super good.

I was wondering if it was possible to attach a Quest 2 controller to the top of the camera and harvest the motion data from that to an object in Blender?

I have seen that it is possible in UE4 but I was wondering if there was an extension or maybe a way where I could get access to the raw data where I could make an extension.

Comment: if you can figure out how to get the Quest tracking data into a [bvh](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Courses/cs-838-1999/Jeff/BVH.html) file you could use the bvh importer to enter it as tracking data